# Downloading multiple files with curl with different proxies

Tags: unix, proxy

I'm trying to download multiple urls from different domains using different proxies.

It should do all these in one row of code, running curl just once:

```
do shell script "curl --proxy 1.2.3.4:800 http://domain1.com/somefile.txt"
do shell script "curl --proxy 2.3.4.5:80 http://www.domain2.com/otherfile.png"
do shell script "curl --proxy 3.4.5.6:8080 http://domain3.com/file.jpg"
...
```

This fails:

```
do shell script "curl --proxy 1.2.3.4:800 2.3.4.5:80 3.4.5.6:8080 http://domain1.com/somefile.txt http://www.domain2.com/otherfile.png http://domain3.com/file.jpg"
```

---

Taking the code from an answer below I tried to run

```
set url_list to "1.2.3.4:800 http://domain1.com/somefile.txt
2.3.4.5:80 http://www.domain2.com/otherfile.png
3.4.5.6:8080 http://domain3.com/file.jpg"

do shell script "xargs curl --proxy < " & url_list
```

but this fails as well.

Comment: How does the second example fail (error message etc.)? And to the question as a whole: What do you expect from running the three downloads in one row of code? Do you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: There is no need to run parallel.

Comment: What is the motivation to have it all in "one row of code" then?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a long URL or multiples, use xargs instead:

```
do shell script "xargs curl --proxy < url-list.txt"
```

url-list.txt

```
1.2.3.4:800 http://domain1.com/somefile.txt
2.3.4.5:80 http://www.domain2.com/otherfile.png
3.4.5.6:8080 http://domain3.com/file.jpg
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also pass `-L 1 -P 3` to `xargs` as well to ensure that `curl` is called correctly and that `xargs` runs the downloads in parallel?

Comment: @patrix, yes I normally would, although the `op` didn't have any of those args in their original command - so maybe they didn't want any reattempts. Proxy tunnel args are only necessary if not using HTTP protocol.

Comment: I would pass them to xargs, not to curl.

Comment: lol, ironic how those args still apply to the question in the curl aspect - but yes xargs eof and output is helpful no doubt and sorry i didn't notice that in your original comment.